# can't use FirebaseRecyclerViewAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I want to use Firebase UI library allowing views to be updated in realtime as they change, and for displaying lists with FirebaseRecyclerViewAdapter.

I am trying to use similar code for my recyclerview with my model class and holder but getting error

```
adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerViewAdapter<ChatMessage, ,      ChatMessageViewHolder>(ChatMessage.class, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,  ChatMessageViewHolder.class, mRef) {
     public void populateViewHolder(ChatMessageViewHolder chatMessageViewHolder, ChatMessage chatMessage) {
         chatMessageViewHolder.nameText.setText(chatMessage.getName());
         chatMessageViewHolder.messageText.setText(chatMessage.getMessage());
     }
 };
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: You have two commands in your generic type list `ChatMessage, ,      ChatMessageViewHolder`. Is that the error you're getting?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen , Having same issue "firebase-ui:0.1.0"  FirebaseRecyclerViewAdapter's constructor doesn't match your github description or demo project either.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen added 0.2.0 via module dependencies and works smooth like in example... something wrong with gradle only + in github docs you either user 0.1.0 or 0.2.0 while examples are clearly for later.

Comment: A link to said docs would be very welcome. The example with ListView should work with 0.1 and 0.2. The example with RecyclerView is for 0.2 only (the order of the constructor arguments was changed).